# Implement GPS Navigation in Android Application while moving user

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, navigation, android-gps

#### Actually, I want to Add GPS navigation

Which shows the direction while User will move with locations in android application, but no source found and I am new to this topic, Please Give me some suggestion or hint for this task, how to use in the application

Answer (score 1):

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

http://www.todroid.com/how-to-create-a-google-map-application-using-android-studio/

Source is also attached.It will help you integrate location module in your apps.

Comment: Thank You santak!! But it just show latitude and longitude actually what i want to do is  when user is moving with location at that time navigation also should move.